# How to read current screen orientation on Android?

Tags: android, androidx, android-orientation, android-displaymanager

I would like to read current screen orientation on Android using Jetpack Compose.

I already tried following in a `@Composable`:

```
val o = LocalActivity.current.requestedOrientation

val o = LocalContext.current.display.rotation

val o = LocalActivity.current.resources.configuration.orientation
```

but in vain.

```
Log.d("Orientation", "The Orientation $o")
```

Everytime, I rotate the orientation, log outputs on these remain the same. So they do not seem to change.

How can I read the screen orientation?

Comment: "Everytime, I rotate the orientation, log outputs on these remain the same" -- you might want to expand your [mcve] to show when and how you are logging these values. Beyond that, though, bear in mind that with split screen, freeform multi-window (Chrome OS, Samsung DeX, etc.), foldables, and the changes coming in Android 12L, that "orientation" is becoming an obsolete concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalConfiguration.current.orientation
```

solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could override `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method of your activity.

To get this method called you also need to specify the changing in android:configChanges attribute in your manifest file.

See what and how to specify, kindly check [this docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges).

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from `BoxWithConstraints` and compare the **width** with the **height**.

A simple example:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
          //Our composable that gets the screen orientation
            BoxWithConstraints {
                val mode = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                mode.value = if (maxWidth < maxHeight) "Portrait" else "Landscape"
                Text(text = "Now it is in ${mode.value} mode")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: orientation is not just Portrait or Landscape. It can be 0, 90, 180, 270 degree rotation. There any way to determine the degree?